# django proxy user model access username

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am writing a self Service Application for our Employees based on django 2.0 . Now I want to extend the django user model with an proxy model. But how can i access the username of the user object from the proxy model?

```
class IDM(User):
    idmclient = idm(settings.IDM_USER, settings.IDM_USER_PASS)
    groups = []
    for group in idmclient.getUser(samaccountname=super.username).get_groups():
        group = group.__dict__
        groups.append(group)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ('username', )
```

Comment: Can you post the models pls?

Comment: You need to extend the AbstractUser class

Comment: Take a look: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models. Your proxy model is simply another way to call your parent model. But it has same fields. In fact, they are stored in same table! So, in your case, all your employees proxy models will have also `username` field.

Comment: If i remove the super i get a NameError(`name 'username' is not defined`)

Comment: Consider a [*Profile* model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) instead is my advice. That would have a OneToOne relationship with the builtin auth `User` model. Then you could do `some_profile.user.username` for example. Or `some_user.profile.idmclient` from the other end of the relationship. (assuming you use `'profile'` as the `related_name`)

Comment: Usually I do what @sytech said and create a profile one

Comment: @systech I switched to the Profile model but here i got a similar error `AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'username'`

Comment: how are you trying to access it? update your question with the relevant code and full traceback

Answer (score 0):

I think im complete on the wrong way. I want to add dynamic content to the Django user object at runtime.

What is the best way to do this?